# how do I check the version of Cypress I have installed via command line

Tags: version, cypress

I want to check the version I have of Cypress that is installed via the command line.

how do I check that
I have tried Cypress verify
and cypress version

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to use command `./node_modules/.bin/cypress version` to get the cypress version.

Answer (score 10):

In the project folder type:

npx cypress --version

Answer (score 7):

In the terminal type `cypress -v` or `cypress --version`

Answer (score 1):

Use Git-Bash/Cmd, type "npx cypress --version".  It will give Cypress package version, Cypress binary version, Electron and Bundled Node version also.  Typing "./node_modules/.bin/cypress version" in cmd prompt will also give the same details.